# Can't replace image when I click panel croussel item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find a way to replace an image (used cats as an example) when I click one panel that isn't the one i've clicked before.

```
if (clicked=="panel1" && (document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility == "hidden")) || (clicked=="panel1" && ((document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility == "visible") || (document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility == "visible")))
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I'm not quite sure why.

Also, i'm not quite sure how to have all three images in the same spot; I've tried to have them all inside the same div, with no success.

Finally, is it possible to have only one panel open? My idea was if we click one, the previously opened one was supposed to close.

```js
        var el_down = document.getElementById("accordion");
        <!-- var cliques = document.getElementById("cliques"); -->
        var div = 0;
        <!-- var height = document.panel.style.height; -->
        document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        function clicado(clicked){
            el_down.innerHTML = "ID = "+clicked;
            div++;
            //<!-- el_down.innerHTML = "painel = "+height; -->
        if (clicked=="panel1" && div%2!="0"){
        //if (clicked=="panel1" && (document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility == "hidden")) || (clicked=="panel1" && ((document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility == "visible") || (document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility == "visible"))){
            document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        if (clicked=="panel2" && div%2!="0"){
            // document.getElementById("imagemLat1").style.visibility = "hidden"; -->
            document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility = "visible";
            // document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility = "hidden"; -->
            }
            else{
            document.getElementById("imagemLat2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        if (clicked=="panel3" && div%2!="0"){
            document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else{
            document.getElementById("imagemLat3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

        
        }
        
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    var el_down = document.getElementById("accordion");
    var cliques = document.getElementById("cliques");
    var div = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length ; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(clicado) {
        this.classList.toggle("toggle");
        div++;
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }

        }
    );
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  /* background-color: #777; */
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  /* background-color: #ccc; */
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.toggle:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Third party plugin CSS-->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Third party plugin JS-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts_test.js"></script>
        <!-- Scroll function !-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>



                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                            <br><div class="h4 text-white-75 mb-2"><h3><i class="fa fa-lightbulb" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ambiente</h3></div>

                            <p id = "accordion"> </p>
                            <button class="accordion" id="panel1" onclick="clicado(this.id)">Dimensionamento do espaço</button> 
                            <div class="panel">
                              <br><p>Quantas vezes já ouviu queixas sobre a sua cozinha com pouca luz ou sentiu dores de cabeça e desconforto com luz demasiado forte?</p>
                                <p style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">É fundamental determinar a quantidade de luz e de luminárias para cada ambiente, uma vez que a iluminação excessiva pode causar desconforto ocular e aumentar despesas com a eletricidade, e uma iluminação insuficiente pode causar diversos problemas graves para a sua saúde física, mental e social.</p>
                                <p style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">Com uma análise cuidada dos objetivos para cada ambiente em estudo e das especificações que o cliente pretende, é possível calcular e projetar soluções adequadas às necessidades dos clientes de forma eficiente e sustentável.</p>
                            </div>
                            <button class="accordion" id="panel2" onclick="clicado(this.id)">Posicionamento de luminárias para um melhor aproveitamento</button>
                            <div class="panel">
                              <br><p style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">No decorrer da realização do estudo luminotécnico, o tipo de iluminação pretendido e os objetos existentes no espaço em estudo, são de extrema relevância, pois estes são indispensáveis para projetar uma iluminação eficiente, posicionando as luminárias da melhor forma, tendo sempre em conta as atividades que serão realizadas no ambiente em estudo.</p>
                            </div>
                            <button class="accordion"  id="panel3" onclick="clicado(this.id)">Personalizar ambientes de acordo com a necessidade</button>
                            <div class="panel">
                             <br><p style="text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;">Cada cliente tem as suas próprias especificações e necessidades, e cada espaço tem uma função especifica.<br>O estudo luminotécnico permite personalizar e adaptar o espaço às necessidades reais de cada cliente. </p>
                            </div>
                                
                                
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5"><br><br><br>
                                <div class="sidebar-image">
                                    <div class="imagemLateral">

                                        <a id="imagemLat1" href="testMain.html"><span style="display: block;" id= "cliques"><img id="logo1" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fleIpdMXopc/maxresdefault.jpg"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sidebar-image">
                                    <div class="imagemLateral">
                                        <a id="imagemLat2" href="testMain.html"><span style="display: block;" id= "cliques"><img id="logo2" src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/classifieds/2013/10/02/438916/large/lovely-1-year-old-tabby-cat-female-524c0ebc2c3f1.jpg"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sidebar-image">
                                    <div class="imagemLateral">
                                        <a id="imagemLat3" href="testMain.html"><span style="display: block;" id= "cliques"><img id="logo3" src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/classifieds/2013/08/21/398215/large/1-year-old-male-fluffy-white-cat-52147ca5d8b39.jpg"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

</body>

        
        
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can achieve this by the following ways in **below snippet** .
The first code which is commented in **JS** is **dynamic** one but it don't work as you need **(** that is when one accordion is clicked then others are closed **)** but it is fast because you can work with as many accordion as you want using single **JS** .

```js
//function panelClick(reed) {
//  reed.classList.toggle("active");
//  var daad = reed.nextElementSibling;
//  if (daad.style.display === "block") {
//    daad.style.display = "none";
//  } else {
//    daad.style.display = "block";
//  }
//}

function panelClick1() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[1].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[2].style.display = "none";
  var daad = document.getElementById("panel1Content");
  if (daad.style.display === "block") {
    daad.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    daad.style.display = "block";
  }

  var reed = document.getElementById("panel1Img");
  if (reed.style.display === "block") {
    reed.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    reed.style.display = "block";
  }
  document.getElementById("panel2Img").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("panel3Img").style.display = "none";
}

function panelClick2() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[2].style.display = "none";
  var daad = document.getElementById("panel2Content");
  if (daad.style.display === "block") {
    daad.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    daad.style.display = "block";
  }

  document.getElementById("panel1Img").style.display = "none";
  var reed = document.getElementById("panel2Img");
  if (reed.style.display === "block") {
    reed.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    reed.style.display = "block";
  }
  document.getElementById("panel3Img").style.display = "none";
}

function panelClick3() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[1].style.display = "none";
  var daad = document.getElementById("panel3Content");
  if (daad.style.display === "block") {
    daad.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    daad.style.display = "block";
  }
  document.getElementById("panel1Img").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("panel2Img").style.display = "none";
  var reed = document.getElementById("panel3Img");
  if (reed.style.display === "block") {
    reed.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    reed.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  /* background-color: #777; */
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}

.panelImg {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="accordion" id="panel1" onclick="panelClick1()"> Panel1</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel1Content">
    <p>This is 1st pannel content</p>
  </div>


  <button class="accordion" id="panel2" onclick="panelClick2()">Panel2</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel2Content">
    <p>This is 2nd pannel content</p>
  </div>


  <button class="accordion" id="panel3" onclick="panelClick3()">Panel3</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel3Content">
    <p>This is 3rd pannel content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</div>

<img src="#1" alt="#1" id="panel1Img" class="panelImg">
<img src="#2" alt="#2" id="panel2Img" class="panelImg">
<img src="#3" alt="#3" id="panel3Img" class="panelImg">
```

Also , instead of changing images put them in `panelContent`'s `<div>` element so they will hide and show with accordion and it will reduce some of the code making execution a little bit fast

Comment: Well, this did the trick! Thanks for your help!
I think my issue was trying to do everything at the same time instead of separating into various functions. This served as a lesson :D
Still there's something odd. With a merge of my code and yours, I get the results but the accordion content "+" and "-" seem to be "buggy". When you click another panel, the original one does not turn back to "+"... I guess I'll have to live with it. I'm a begginer at this so I supose I'll learn